# show success error message with fadein fadeout effect in Codeigniter with Bootstrap Alert

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I made Crud System in Codeigniter with name, email fields, its works fine, but after completing insert, update or delete it shows success message in bootstrap alert in view part.

but i want bootstrap alert message shows & after some seconds it will fadeout.

**Controller Code:-**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User_model');
    }   

    public function create()
    {   

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required');        
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email');      

        if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
                $this->load->view('create');
            }
        else{
            $formArray = array();
            $formArray['name']=$this->input->post('name');
            $formArray['email']=$this->input->post('email');
            $formArray['created_at']= date('Y-m-d');

            $this->User_model->create($formArray);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Record added Successfully!!!');
            redirect(base_url().'User/index');  
        }       
    }
}
?>
```

**Model Code:-**

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {

        function create($formArray){
            $this->db->insert('users',$formArray);  
        } 
    }
?>
```

**Insert Form Part :-**

```
<div class="row">
        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url().'User/create';?>">
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name :</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('name');?>"  >
                <span style="color:red;"><?php echo form_error('name');?></span>    
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email-Id :</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>" >
                <span style="color:red;"><?php echo form_error('email');?></span>       
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button> 
                <a href="<?php echo base_url().'User/index'; ?>" class="btn btn-info">Cancel</a>    
            </div>

        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**View Code Part:-**

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <?php 
           if($this->session->flashdata('success')){
         ?>
           <div class="alert alert-success "> 
             <?php  echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
        <?php    
        } else if($this->session->flashdata('error')){
        ?>
         <div class = "alert alert-danger">
           <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
         </div>
        <?php } ?>

     </div>
```

Comment: Where are you setting $this->session->flashdata('error'). I cannot see it in your code.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw in Controller Code last line i use this.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw in controller code the last line i use  `$this->session->set_flashdata('success','Record added Successfully!!!');` but how to handle `error` messages in that?

Comment: You set the error flashdata when you error and show it in your create view. As that is where you want to show the error.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw but in which condition the `error` message is shown?

Comment: What do you mean? You show a success message when you have success, and you show an error message when you have an error. I'm not sure if you understand your own code.

Comment: An error will be when your form validation Fails (errors)... You need to add that in.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw i understand my own code.

Comment: So tell me - what is the purpose of your error message - what do you want to show the user?

Answer (score 0):

**View Code Part:-**

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <?php 
           if($this->session->flashdata('success')){
         ?>
           <div class="alert alert-success "  style="display:none;"> 
             <?php  echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
        <?php    
        } else if($this->session->flashdata('error')){
        ?>
         <div class = "alert alert-danger"  style="display:none;">
           <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
         </div>
        <?php } ?>

     </div>
```

**Add script like that:-**

```
$(".alert").fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(5000);
```

Comment: @KUMAR,  the display:none style hides it and the jquery statement is meant to show it ( It does work I just tried it ). So you need to have the jquery lib loaded prior to the script shown. Sorav might update his answer to make this clearer, or use document.ready()

Comment: @KUMAR can you please share the view page source?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" rel="stylesheet">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $(".alert").fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(5000);
    });
</script>

Comment: @KUMAR use like that.

Comment: Yes , it worked, but how can i implement `error` message in that?

Comment: the same process will work, that you are following. Can you please mark upvote if its working.